# How to use dynamic keys with NodeJS MongoDB driver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to update a document in one of my MongoDB Atlas documents using the following code where productID is a local variable:

```js
await collection.updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId(userID) }, { $inc: { [productID]: 1 } }, { upsert: true });
```

however I don't seem to be able to use dynamic keys within $inc as I get the following error:

Type '{ [x: string]: number; }' is not assignable to type 'AcceptedFields...

Is there any way of dynamically setting the key when using $inc?